# JPA + Hibernate : catch block inside a Transactional method is never reached

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, persistence

I have a class **a_DAO** that is annotated as **@Transactional** and inside it I have a method called **x(String token)**. This method is called inside the **b_BC** class method called **y()** which is also annotated as **@Transactional** and also called another method that does persistence as well. The problem is that in the **x()** method a UK exception can occur in the database and I'd like to catch before the container does persistence in the database.

**a_DAO.class**

```
@Singleton
@Transactional
public class a_DAO {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    a_DAO() {
    }

    public static a_DAO getInstance() {
        return CDI.current().select(a_DAO.class).get();
    }

    /* If a UK problem occurs here I'd like to throw the exception before the container does it. */
    public void x(String token) {
        try {
            em.persist(token);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Here I'd like do intercept the error");
        }
    }
}
```

**b_BC.class**

```
public class b_BC {

@Transactional
public void y() {

    /*
     my business logic
    */

    a_DAO.getInstance().insert(token);

    // c_DAO is another DAO
    c_DAO.getInstance().insert("xxx");

}
```

Comment: wait ... so your problem is that your code doesn't throw an Exception?

Comment: The exception is thrown when the transaction is finalized, but in a given case I wanted to capture before the transaction ends.

Comment: Use ```flush``` method. The statement is only executed against the db when the session flushes entity updates, which can occurs (automatically) at transaction commitment, or when you explicitly call flush to the entitymanager.

Comment: When using em.flush () the error occurs in insert method from c_DAO: javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: WFLYJPA0060: Transaction is required to perform this operation (either use a transaction or extended persistence context)

Comment: then you have an (other) issue with your transaction manager configuration...

Comment: is your c_dao annotated with ```@Transactional``` too?

Comment: yes. c_dao is annotated with @Transactional.

Comment: I tried change the @PersistenceContext to @PersistenceContext(type = EXTENDED) and did not resolved.

Comment: I was asking on your transaction manager configuration, either local or global, with some default propagation and isolation. With transaction propagation = REQUIRED (the default), it should start a new one if none exists, or continue an existing transaction. Additionally, putting transactional on the repository is quite odd. It usually goes to the service layer...